# installed bc but cannot run it

Tags: command-line, executable

I installed bc from the repository using apt-get, but cannot make it run whatever I do.
Can anyone please explain the following...?

```
[~]$ pwd
/home/polaris
[~]$ bc
File /home/polaris/.bc is unavailable.
[~]$ which bc
/usr/bin/bc
[~]$ /usr/bin/bc
File /home/polaris/.bc is unavailable.
[~]$ file /usr/bin/bc
/usr/bin/bc: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for 
GNU/Linux 3.2.0, 
BuildID[sha1]=c98017fef306eb7d7f1b9699bf463622ad34125a, stripped
```

It is a 64-bit binary executable, and my system is 64-bit.
There is no alias to it.  Why is it looking for a .bc in my home directory?  I am completely baffled.

Comment: Does `touch /home/polaris/.bc` help? `.bc` is a settings file, ie the default settings are stored there.

Comment: What you have provided looks okay to me, fyi: I do not have `$HOME/.bc` on my system and it starts, so I'd check you have some disk space in your $HOME  (for creation of the file during operation)

Answer (score 4):

You probably have the environment variable BC_ENV_ARGS set to .bc.  Remove that setting (maybe in .bashrc, .profile, etc.) and things should work.  Try

```
unset BC_ENV_ARGS
```

and then

```
bc
```

to see if that fixes things temporarily.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  Thanks very much.  I remember now that I added something to .bashrc as part of setting the default "scope" of bc to another value than the default, and that must have been the reason it was there.  I have removed it.  But setting the scope to 2 by default was very useful.  I wish I could remember how...